# cannot login to sql server due logon trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, authentication

I have an urgent situation

I write a logon trigger for disable to login from hacking programs but it blocked me to and none of the users cannot logon database my trigger is

```
  /****** Object:  DdlTrigger [connection_limit_trigger]    Script Date: 08/13/2011 08:43:04 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER TRIGGER [connection_limit_trigger]
ON ALL SERVER 
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN

   IF EXISTS (SELECT    row_count,* FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions  
   WHERE  1 = 1
        AND (program_name NOT IN ('myappname', 'Microsoft Office 2003','Microsoft Office 2007','Report Server','Microsoft SQL Server' ))        
        AND (program_name NOT LIKE '%Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio%') 
        OR host_name is not null


    )
    BEGIN
       ROLLBACK;
    END;
END;


--DROP TRIGGER connection_limit_trigger ON ALL SERVER

GO

SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

ENABLE TRIGGER [connection_limit_trigger] ON ALL SERVER
GO
```

now I cannot logon to database can I delete all triggers on sql ? is there any way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you are unable to logon due to a bug in the LOGON trigger you have created.

You can delete (DROP) the trigger under a Dedicated Administrator Connection (DAC).

```
sqlcmd -A -D master (as a sysadmin)
```

- [Using a Dedicated Administrator Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189595.aspx)
- [How to: Use the Dedicated Administrator Connection with SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068.aspx)

Comment: thanks mitch I connected with this command :sqlcmd -S LocalHost -d master -A
 and run this query : DROP TRIGGER connection_limit_trigger ON ALL SERVER
and it worked

Answer (score 0):

For the future might I recommend that you add something like this. At least while you are testing.

```
    IF IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin', ORIGINAL_LOGIN()) = 1
        OR ORIGINAL_LOGIN() = 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'
        BEGIN
            GOTO ERROREND
        END
```

ERROREND: -- near the end of the trigger