# Disable logon trigger in Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have such problem as described in 
[cannot login to sql server due logon trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048923/cannot-login-to-sql-server-due-logon-trigger)

But I use Oracle. Is there same thing like "Dedicated Admin Connection"?
Or are there any other method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

In Oracle, a user with the `ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER` privilege should be able to log in even if a logon trigger throws an error.  That should include any users with the DBA role.

Comment: In my case logon trigger don't throw any error. But in it there is a call of function sleep(1800)... So to logon I have to wait half an hour, but when I try to drop this tigger timeout happened

Answer (score 2):

Up to Oracle ver. 10g (including) the logon trigger was not fired for users having DBA role.
Since ver. 11g it's fired also for DBA sessions, but its failure does not kill the session.

For all the other users any error thrown from the logon trigger kills the session.

So if you want to administer the logon trigger, you should connect as sysdba (`sqlplus / as sysdba`)

PS: also note, that aside from `LOGON TRIGGER ON DATABASE` there is also a `LOGON TRIGGER ON SCHEMA` which is less dangerous.